# Unit testing an object of type boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost

I have a unit test which looks something like this:

```
typedef boost::variant<std::vector<std::string, ...> > Container;
TEST_F (TestAppend, emptyContainer)
{
    Container container((std::vector<std::string>()));
    Append append("stringValueToAppend"); 
    boost::apply_visitor(append(), container);
    ...
}
```

I will need to test that the container is still of type `std::vector<std::string>()` having applied the visitor. I will then need to extract the `vector<string>` from the variant so as to test its contents.

What is a convenient approach to doing these two things?

RTTI is enabled.

Comment: why is RTTI not enabled for unit tests?

Comment: @BЈовић I've now removed the flag that was disabling RTTI in the unit test environment so it is now enabled!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `boost::get` to check what type the `boost::variant` is.  If you pass in a pointer then it will return `NULL` if the variant isn't of the type you requested.

So you could do something like this:

```
ASSERT_TRUE( boost::get< std::vector<std::string> >( &container ) != NULL );
```

Alternatively you could pass in a reference rather than a pointer and it will throw a `bad_get` exception

[Documentation is here for more information](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/get_id1573726.html)

Comment: You probably mean `get<vector<string> >`.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think its a valid test to check the type of the variant since I don't think its possible for the variant to change type via its visitor. Instead I should just get a std::vector<std::string> as suggested via boost::get and then test its contents.